# SQL Server job timeout

Tags: sql-server

So, it seems that it is not possible to set the timeout for each single step in a SQL Server job ([article from StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200527/how-to-set-sql-server-2005-job-cmdexec-timeout)).

MSDN points out that you can of course set the Agent timeout:

- [Sql Server Agent properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189727.aspx).
- [Set Job execution shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190239.aspx).

**Questions**

1. How does Agent time-out work?
2. Is there any other way (preferably by configuration) to setup the single step timeout?
3. Is there any other way (preferably by configuration) to setup the whole job timeout?

Answer (score 4):

(1) is referring to the service itself. If I go stop the SQL Server Agent service this value specifies how long it will wait for any active job to complete before forcible stopping it (the service) so it can shutdown.

With regards to (2) and (3), you would have to setup some [monitoring script/job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588599/sql-server-agent-job-timeout) that tracks that information and performs an action based on your criteria.